# zoom in or zoom out not working in mediaelementjs in ie8 or othe browser shich support flash

Tags: mediaelement.js

**Using Mediaelementjs** while playing the video in **ie8** or othe browse which **support flash**, when using the **zoom in or zoom out** the player frame size is not increasing or decrising with respect  to the browser. Any one can help me to solve this problem. Thanks